# Magento 2 REST API filter products in stock

Tags: magento2, product, api, rest-api

I am looking for an API filter to get in stock products but I could not find any option on the internet.

Any ideas ? Maybe some plugin code ?

Thanks !

Comment: you can create your custom rest api for it.

Comment: Excuse me but what you mean ? A separate API, a new API endpoing ? I think it would be too hard work and there would be confusion for the API client developer to work with. Any ideas of using the original endpoint with this filter ? Thans !!

Comment: are you looking for the code to get in stock products only?

Comment: @ChandreshChauhan I am looking for a code to add an option to filter by in stock products. I mean the default list should keep the same, but if this field is set in the searchcriteria then it should filter.